# How can you anchor a QPushButton to a specific location on a QScrollArea?

Tags: python, pyqt, pyqt5, qlabel, qscrollarea

I have a large map that is contained within a scrollable area. What I want is to be able to do is click on the name of a country, the name being a PyQt5 QPushButton. What I currently have now is a button that stays in the same place in regards to the screen but not the map:

```
import sys

from PyQt5.QtGui import QPixmap, QPalette
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QApplication, QScrollArea, QLabel, QPushButton


class MapGUI(QScrollArea):

    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.initUI()

    def initUI(self):
        screen_resolution = app.desktop().screenGeometry()
        width, height = screen_resolution.width(), screen_resolution.height()
        self.setGeometry(0, 0, height, height)
        self.setWindowTitle("The World")

        self.label = QLabel()
        self.pixmap_unscaled = QPixmap("The_World.png")
        # Scaling the image to half the size
        self.pixmap = self.pixmap_unscaled.scaled(int(self.pixmap_unscaled.width() * 0.5), int(self.pixmap_unscaled.height() * 0.5))
        self.label.setPixmap(self.pixmap)

        self.button = QPushButton('PyQt5 button', self)
        self.button.setToolTip('This is an example button')
        self.button.setGeometry(100, 100, 100, 50)


        self.setBackgroundRole(QPalette.Dark)
        self.setWidget(self.label)

        self.show()


if __name__ == "__main__":

    app = QApplication(sys.argv)

    map = MapGUI()

    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

By doing this the button is static. Is there a way to tie the movement of the map the movement of the button so when I scroll the button follows along?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The position of a widget is relative to your parent, in your case the parent of the button is the `QScrollArea`, but since you want it to move next to the `QLabel`, this must be your parent, in your case it changes:

```
self.button = QPushButton('PyQt5 button', self)
```

to:

```
self.button = QPushButton('PyQt5 button', self.label)
```

[image]

[image]